# How to get npm or sass to install globally?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

I've been watching tutorials and searching all over, and I've seen several similar issues on here. But none with the same errors. So I apologize if this has been answered before.

I'm taking a self-paced coding class. And I'm supposed to install sass. I finally found a tutorial that seemed straightforward. But when I entered the commands I'm getting error codes in my terminal. I'm very new to all this, so I have no idea what any of this means.

Some context: I downloaded homebrew, but didn't understand that either (so I uninstalled it). So then I Followed [THIS](https://youtu.be/wYWf2m_yzBQ?t=404) tutorial where I downloaded node.js/npm. And everything went fine until I tried the `install -g sass` command. Then I started getting all these messages and going down the rabbit hole. [Npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) has some info on this issue, but I couldn't figure it out. It mentions reinstalling npm, or using "nvm". But when I tried the command `npm install -g npm` it returned very similar errors.

```
carlosprieto@Carloss-Mac-mini ~ % npm install -g sass
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/carlosprieto/.npm/_logs/2022-06-17T16_02_28_018Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Read the first line of the error: `npm WARN config global '--global', '--local' are deprecated. Use '--location=global' instead`. So, replace `-g` with `--location=global`. Then, try running the command with `sudo` (i.e., `sudo npm install --location=global ...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need admin access, using `sudo` should help you

`sudo npm i -g sass`

this means you have superuser access, and is required to install packages globally.

read more here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/sudo.htm

Comment: That worked!

I dont understand why haha. I am the Admin. So why I wouldn't have specific permissions is confusing. 

Also, I read in a few places to avoid using 'sudo' for some reason. Im not gonna worry about it now though.

Thank you.